# How to restrict the empty file upload control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

Using JQuery I am restricting the file extension but I am getting an issue is that "If I don't upload any video just I am clicking the upload button its not validating". This is my code, what editing I have to do?

**Sample.aspx**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $(function () {
    $('#<%=FileUploadbtn.ClientID %>').change(
             function () {
                 var fileExtension = ['mp4'];
                 if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                     // alert("Invalid");
                     $('#<%=uploadbtn.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", true);
                     $('#<%= lblError.ClientID %>').html("Invalid");
                 }
                 else {
                     $('#<%=uploadbtn.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", false);
                     $('#<%= lblError.ClientID %>').html(" ");
                 }
             })
})
```

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="button" OnClick="uploadbtn_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: why are you using javascript, as you can do it with simple `RequiredFieldValidator`

Comment: I need to play only MP4 file, so i am using JavaScript, It is possible for RequiredFieldValidator?? Can you share the code,According to my require? Please Help

Comment: U need to search a bit for video upload. Other than that my answer will work for file upload

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'requiredfieldvalidator' for the fileupload control.Works just fine.

Comment: How to write requiredfieldvalidator, can u explain with my code? how to write

Comment: the code has been given by 'Nadeem' above and i guess it worked.

Answer (score 0):

*There is no need of using Javascript as you are implementing it. You can simply use asp.net Required Field validator to implement what you trying to achieve.*

Here you go, its very simple:-

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadbtn" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requpload" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUploadbtn" ValidationGroup="abc" ErrorMessage="Please select the file"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="uploadbtn" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="button" OnClick="uploadbtn_Click" ValidationGroup="abc" />
```

**Note** Dont forget to add `ValidationGroup` as it will validate properly the control to which this attribute is added

Here is some documentation related to Required Field Validator. Please go through the link for some knowledge.

[RequiredField Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope that helps

Comment: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).   "I Am GETTING THIS ERROR.."

Comment: Actually i am getting same ERROR....If i am removing RequiredFieldValidator its working but The empty file also uploading

Comment: Search for the error on the net.i am on mobile so cant be able to help much. However my answer will perfectly work for file upload validation.

Comment: OKay thanks for your help, if it is possible help me.. THANK YOU

Comment: Do one thing. Take a new aspx page and try again with this much of functionality. I guess u will get an idea what u r doing wrong

Comment: Got the Solution,Its Working Now, Just i am posting the ANSWER  " Now add key for Unobtrusive under <appSettings> tag as following code. "  " <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>"

Comment: why does she have to remove jquery at the first place? She needs jquery for restricting users to upload only mp4 files.Anyways,i guess she figured it out now.